# Does Fortify sourceanalyzer support aar files?

Tags: aar, fortify

I can add jar files to my classpath when using sourceanalyzer, but it doesn't seem to pick up source in aar files.

There is no mention of aar in Fortify SCA User's Guide but I am not 100% sure it is up to date, so I was hoping for an authoritative confirmation that it is indeed not supported. I am a bit surprised that would be the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer is no - it is expecting JARs.

From SCA 16.10 Guide:

> **Translating Android Projects**
>
> Translating Android projects is similar to translating Java code. See "Translating Java Code" on page 20 for
> more information